# Change color bar title in plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying change the scale title in plotly but am a little stumped. Here is the basic plot I am creating:

```
library(sf)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc %>% 
  plot_ly(split = ~AREA, 
          color = ~AREA,
          showlegend = FALSE)
```

Now really what I want is to change the title of currently specified by "AREA". You *can* change the title of the plot like so:

```
nc %>% 
  plot_ly(split = ~AREA, 
          color = ~AREA, 
          showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(legend=list(title=list(text='<b> A title? </b>')))
```

My first attempt was to simply replace legend with scale:

```
nc %>% 
  plot_ly(split = ~AREA, 
          color = ~AREA, 
          showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(scale=list(title=list(text='<b> A title? </b>')))
```

that didn't work and neither did this:

```
nc %>% 
  plot_ly(split = ~AREA, 
          color = ~AREA, 
          colorbar = "foo",
          showlegend = FALSE)
```

Any ideas how I can change the title for the colorbar?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there... Try this:

```
library(sf)
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

nc = st_read(system.file('shape/nc.shp', package = 'sf'))
title = '' # insert your title here
nc %>% 
  plot_ly(split = ~AREA, color = ~AREA, showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
  layout(legend = list(title = list(text = paste('<b>', title, '</b>'))))
```

Let me know if it solved your problem...